# How to set multiple themes in Tailwind css

Tags: css, next.js, themes, tailwind-css

I know how to set dark and light theme in tailwind, what i'm asking is how would i extend this to include different ones, like having a theme called pink, blue, red, etc, and being like dark mode where you say

```
<p className="text-black dark:text-white">Color</p>
```

But what i want to do is be able to do this

```
<p className="text-black dark:text-white orange:text-orange blue:text-blue">Color</p>
```

is this possible regular tailwind css,

as well im using next-themes for switching between dark and light theme and it says to pass different themes into it like this

```
<ThemeProvider themes={['pink', 'red', 'blue', 'light', 'dark']}>
```

I am able to switch between them like this

```
 const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme()

<select
        value={theme}
        onChange={(e) => setTheme(e.target.value)}
        className="light-contrast:bg-orange-300"
      >
        <option value="system">System</option>
        <option value="dark">Dark</option>
        <option value="light">Light</option>
        <option value="light-contrast">light-contrast</option>
        <option value="dark-contrast">dark-contrast</option>
        <option value="dark-dimmed">dark-dimmed</option>
      </select>
```

The theme does chnage but i want tailwind to be able to pick this up and then set the correct theme styles like mentioned above, like `pink:text-pink` etc

Answer (score 1):

You might try [tw-colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tw-colors). It makes it super easy to setup several dynamic color themes

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
const { createThemes } = require('tw-colors');

   module.exports = {
      content: ['./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'],
      plugins: [
         createThemes({
            halloween: { 
               'primary': 'orange',
               'secondary': 'yellow',
            },
            summer: { 
               'primary': 'pink',
               'secondary': 'red',
            },
            winter: { 
               'primary': 'blue',
               'secondary': 'green',
            },
            party: { 
               'primary': 'steelblue',
               'secondary': 'darkblue',
            },
         })
      ],
   };
```

use themes like this with class:

```html
<html class='theme-halloween'>
      ...
</html>
```

Or with data attributes:

```html
<html data-theme='halloween'>
      ...
</html>
```

Themes can be switched dynamically with some toggle button or whatever you prefer

Answer (score 0):

u need to set different themes
onst defaultConfig = require('path-to-default-config');

> // theme-1-tailwind.config.js
> module.exports = {
> ...defaultConfig,
> theme: {
> ...defaultConfig.theme,
> colors: {
> ...defaultConfig.theme.colors,
> // add colors here
> }
> }
> };
>
> ```
> // theme-2-tailwind.config.js
> ...
>
> // theme-3.tailwind.config.js
> ....
> ```

something like this but not sure how to go about this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).